# Improve my arcpy script for simple querying

Tags: arcpy, code-review

I am quite new to coding python in arcmap so I would like to get my code reviewed and hopefully improved.

I have two Shapefiles, one contain polygons of cities borders and the other is points representing city center of gravity. There is only one point per city but a polygon can coverage several cities.

My goal is that each point will have the objectid of the polygon containing it.

My code complexity is O(N^2) so its little disturbting and probably can be much better but I still dont understand good enough how to go over feature class and selecting each row at a step without looping and quering.

10X advance.

```
import arcpy

# fcYesuvimPolygon holds the location of the polygon feature class. 
fcYesuvimPolygon = "h:/acadwork/Ortho/yesuvim_rec_final.shp"
# fcYesuvimPoint holds the location of the point feature class. 
fcYesuvimPoint = "h:/acadwork/Ortho/yesuvim_name_point.shp"

# create layer for SHP.
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fcYesuvimPoint,"fcYesuvimPoint_lyr")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fcYesuvimPolygon,"fcYesuvimPolygon_lyr")

# Go over the point SHP.
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fcYesuvimPoint,["OID@","PolygonID"]) as cursorPoint:
    for rowPoint in cursorPoint:
        # query for selecting each row.
        qry = "FID = " + str(rowPoint[0])
        # select by attribute of each row FID
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("fcYesuvimPoint_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", qry)
        # select polygons intersecting each point
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("fcYesuvimPolygon_lyr", "INTERSECT", "fcYesuvimPoint_lyr", "", "NEW_SELECTION")
        # Go over selected polygon (one for each point)
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("fcYesuvimPolygon_lyr","OBJECTID") as cursorPolygon:
            for rowPolygon in cursorPolygon:
                # insert the objectid of polygon to point SHP field names Polygon ID
                rowPoint[1] = rowPolygon[0]
                cursorPoint.updateRow(rowPoint)
```

Comment: Code/logic looks good, couple suggestions (not code related) 1. if the data is large (many-many features) you may want to import the two layers into a geodatabase and reference the code to those layers (to take advantage of spatial indexes and that geoprocessing large data is faster when the data is in a database) 2. if data is large copy data/datebase to local computer directory and run process locally instead of over a network drive.

Comment: Simple intersect of two layers or spatial join does that. Output to temp feature class point and bring results back using join.

Comment: For code reviews there is the [codereview.se] Stack Exchange.